# macOS Big Sur - Copy formatted text from app that only supports copying plain text

Tags: macos-big-sur

I am using the Olivetree app on macOS Big Sur, but this would apply to many apps. Some of the text I want to copy is colored and is a superscript. When I copy text from the app, there is only the one Copy command and is copies only plain text.

Is there any special AppleScript command (or other trick) that could copy the text while preserving the color and superscript?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I did not provide any code as a starting point.

The answer to the question is to use drag and drop from applications that support it. This will generally keep original formatting.